# Set Function in semi algebra countably subadditive

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $\mu: C\rightarrow [0,+\infty]$ be a set function where $C$ is a semi algebra in $X$. If $\mu$ is subadditive

i.e. (If $B=\cup_{i\geq 1}A_i$ with $A_i, B$ in $C$ then $\mu(B)\leq \sum \mu(A_i)$)

Then $\mu$ is monotone?

Comment: I'm not sure that subadditivity implies monotonicity. It's clear that additivity on disjoints sets guarantees both subadditivity and monotonicity. But, for example, when talking about outer measures, we usually either (i) require both subadditivity and monotonicity in the definition or (ii) prove monotonicity based on the construction of the outer measure without using subadditivity (as with Lebesgue outer measure). This makes me think the conditions are independent. That being said, I don't have an immediate example of a set function on a semi-algebra which is subadditive and not monotone.